# How to retrieve an Object data type coming as OUT param from Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We are using a stored procedure in an Oracle database. we are calling the stored procedure through Spring data JPA. The stored procedure OUT param is of object type. How to retrieve the object type OUT param coming from the stored procedure in Spring Data JPA?

Please refer to the below block of code that we tried.

Stored procedure:

```
create or replace TYPE outputData
    AS OBJECT (aa varchar2(40), bb varchar2(40), 
    vv varchar2(100), 
    dd varchar2(100), ee NUMBER(10), 
    ff varchar2(1000));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE calculatedOpData AS TABLE OF outputData;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calculator
(name IN varchar2, fromDate IN VARCHAR2,    
toDate IN VARCHAR2, age IN VARCHAR2, result OUT calculatedOpData) 
IS
BEGIN
// ...
END
```

JPA:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
       @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "calculator",
      procedureName = "calculator",
              resultClasses = Object[].class,
      parameters = {
         @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "name", type = String.class),
         @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "fromDate", type = String.class),
         @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "toDate", type = String.class),
         @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "age", type = String.class),
         @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "result", type = Object.class)
      })
    })
```

I am getting this exception.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type [org.hibernate.type.ObjectType@f9a5e3f] does support multi-parameter value extraction

Please help us on the above issue?

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. we went with Spring JDBC Template to resolve this issue.